# Prove that we can arrange some person in a round table so that a person can sit between two people they know

Tags: graph-theory

In a party with at least 3 people. Each person knows at least 2 other people. Prove that we can arrange some people in a round table so that a person can sit between two people they know.

I'm trying to use the handshaking lemma to prove it. I denote the set of vertices contains all the people in the party and there will be a directed edge if this person know the other but i just can prove that when a new person attend the party so he/she will contribute 4 to the sum of deg so that the deg is always even. And i'm stuck here.

Comment: It's easy to arrange this for "a person," do you want to arrange it for all people?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. And the problem is to prove for "some people" but not all people.

Comment: Who is "this person"?  Do you mean each person at the table?

Comment: If knowing someone is symmetric, then in graph theory terms this says that a simple graph where each vertex has degree at least $2$ has a cycle.  This is true an easy to prove,

Comment: The problem don't mention about the knowing relationship is symmetry. Sorry because my english skill is not too good.